# IsDropDownOpen in a DataGrid DataTemplate ComboBox in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I have a `DataGrid` with a ComboBox in a DataTemplate

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Stock Name" Width="290">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StockName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="290" Name="cmbStock" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stocks}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want the ComboBox to DropDownOpen when i reach this DataGridCell using Tab
This include in making the DataGrid Cell in edit mode when i reach it.

I am using WPF MVVM

Comment: i dont know the solution for this. i already has set the IsDropDownOpen Property in the combobox style but for that the Cell should become editable when i tab reach the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to force the data grid into "single-click or tab" edit mode. Basically when the cell is focused force the grid to swtich the CellTemplate to CellEditingTemplate. The code for that is:

```
BeginEdit(); //dataGrid.BeginEdit()
```

Now how and where you hook that up depends on how much work you want to do. You could extend the DataGrid class and introduce DependencyProperty "SingleClickEdit" or whatever you wanna call it. Then when monitor/preview key down and on tab select the cell and force it to be in edit mode. Or if you need it just for that column, you could just monitor:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StockName}" 
           GotFocus="OnGotFocus" 
           PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown"
  ....., or something like that
```

Then in .cs code, in OnGotFocus() for example, call datagrid.BeginEdit().

**EDIT:**(per comments/converation below)

- add SelectionChanged handler to your datagrid
- add IsDropDownOpen = true to your combobox

  ```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
         SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged"
         ....>

  <ComboBox Width="290" Name="cmbStock" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stocks}" 
        ...
        IsDropDownOpen="True"></ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- in .cs

  ```
  private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      dataGrid.BeginEdit();
  }
  ```

That should do it, work in my test :), basically you're forcing the datagrid into edit mode on selection, and in your edit mode, you got the combobox that is already open

Comment: ok, let me type something up real quick to test, and I'll get back to you asap

Comment: yeah, you have to wire a lot more stuff to be able to put datagrid into EditMode. The main problem with my suggestion the way I wrote it, is that TextBlock does not receive the focus, or keyboard focus. I am looking through some of my code that I have done a while ago, there I extended the DataGrid, and wrote my own selectCell() methods, but it's a lot of code..

Comment: Trying to keep things simple, I got an interesting solution, I'll post it in a min..

Comment: On more thing i want to ask you is that i want to have the control of `TAB` using `Enter` and when i reach the last column the enter should work as enter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10405/discussion-between-kishore-jangid-and-denis-morozov)